# Should my outdoor spigot be attached to the foundation?

Tags: plumbing, basement, faucet, plumbing-fixture

On the picture attached, is it a correct way of garden faucet installation? In this case it is drilled through the wall and the pipe goes in the basement where attached with the rest of the in-house pipeline.

But what I mean, isn't it supposed to be set on the concrete part of the basement (you can see the concrete part below the faucet, where the siding finishes)?

[image]

Comment: Why have you assumed that?

Comment: I was assuming that because of squished siding :) As you suggested I could put a wooden block behind the faucet and thus "separate" it from the siding, but I guess it'd still squish the siding?  Thanks for your detailed answer! I accepted it.

Comment: I didn't mean a block of wood. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It isn't necessarily supposed to be attached to or bored through the foundation. Most spigots mount adjacent to where the plumbing travels through the joist cavity. It's simpler from a construction standpoint and puts the spigot at a more usable level. If that isn't an option due to the structure's layout, it could pass through the foundation but should be insulated with a foam sleeve and kept out of contact with the concrete.

That said, you sometimes see a trim block behind the faucet instead of just squished siding. With vinyl siding, though, economy often wins the day.

[image]

[image]